# joda time: getMaximumValue returns wrong value (Islamic chrono.)

Tags: java, android, jodatime

I'm trying to get the number of days in each month in the year(Islamic chronology)

I'm using this function

```
public  int daysOfMonth(int year, int month) {
    MutableDateTime dateTime = new MutableDateTime(IslamicChronology.getInstance());
    dateTime.setDateTime(year, month, 14, 12, 0, 0, 000);
    return dateTime.dayOfMonth().getMaximumValue();
}
```

but I get wrong values in comparison to http://www.islamicfinder.org/Hcal/index.php

for example, I get that no of days in Rabi Al-Thani 1436 is 29 , while its 30.

I can't find where the problem is. Any help?

Comment: Looks like it should be 29 days according to http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Islamic_calendar. Do we know *exactly* which flavour of Islamic calendar that web page is using?

Comment: In fact, *all* the month lengths on Wikipedia are contrary to those on http://www.islamicfinder.org/Hcal/hdate_year.php?year=1436&base=h

Comment: yes, you are right. Its written in islamicfinder website that the "Hijri calendar is according to Makkah", I don't know how it differs and how to handle the issue. I think I may need further search in this issue. Thank you.